# How to create live tiles on UWP

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

I need an example of creating live tiles on uvp.
The documentation doesn't say or i missed how i need to update the tile.
Just a sample code, but I don't understand where to insert it.

Comment: See code project : https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1037059/How-to-Upgrade-Extended-GridView-from-WinRT-to-Uni

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need an example of creating live tiles on uvp. The documentation doesn't say or i missed how i need to update the tile.

Please check this [**Update a live tile from a background task**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/update-a-live-tile-from-a-background-task) document. We could use [`CreateTileUpdaterForApplication()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.notifications.tileupdatemanagerforuser.createtileupdaterforapplication?view=winrt-19041) to get this updater for tile system. and use `Update` method to update tile system.

```
private static void UpdateTile( SyndicationFeed feed )
    {
        // Create a tile update manager for the specified syndication feed.
        var updater = TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication();
        updater.EnableNotificationQueue( true );
        updater.Clear();

        // Keep track of the number feed items that get tile notifications.
        int itemCount = 0;

        // Create a tile notification for each feed item.
        foreach( var item in feed.Items )
        {
            XmlDocument tileXml = TileUpdateManager.GetTemplateContent( TileTemplateType.TileWide310x150Text03 );

            var title = item.Title;
            string titleText = title.Text == null ? String.Empty : title.Text;
            tileXml.GetElementsByTagName( textElementName )[0].InnerText = titleText;

            // Create a new tile notification.
            updater.Update( new TileNotification( tileXml ) );

            // Don't create more than 5 notifications.
            if( itemCount++ > 5 ) break;
        }
    }
```

And this official [code sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/SecondaryTiles) that you could refer.